# Validation on route change in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I have the following tiny dilemma: I have a backbone app, which is almost entirely route based, i.e. if I do to `nameoftheapp/photos/1/edit` I should go to the edit page for a given photo. The problem is, since my view logic happens almost 100% on the client side  (I use a thin service-based server for storage and validation) how do I avoid issues of the sort of an unauthorized user reaching that page? Of course, I can make the router do the check if the user is authorized, but this already leads to duplication of efforts in terms of validation. Of course, I cannot leave the server side without validation, because then the API would be exposed to access of any sort.

I don't see any other way for now. Unless someone comes up with a clever idea, I guess I will have to duplicate validation both client and server-side.

Answer (score 4):

The fundamental rule should be "never trust the client".  Never deliver to the client what they're not allowed to have.

So, if the user goes to `nameoftheapp/photos/1/edit`, presumably you try to fetch the image from the server.

The server should respond with a HTTP 401 response (unauthorized).

Your view should have an error handler for this and inform the user they're not authorized for that - in whatever way you're interested in - an error message on the edit view, or a "history.back()" to return to the previous "page".

So, you don't really have to duplicate the validation logic - you simply need your views to be able to respond meaningfully to the validation responses from the server.

You might say, "That isn't efficient - you end up making more API calls", but those unauthorized calls are not going to be a normal occurrence of a user using the app in any regular fashion, they're going to be the result of probing, and I can find out all the API calls anyway by watching the network tab and hit the API directly using whatever tools I want.  So, there really will be no more API traffic then if you DID have validation in the client.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue a while ago, and it seems the best practice is to use server-side validation. My suggestion... Use a templating engine like Underscore, which is a dependency of Backbone, design the templates, and for those routes that only authenticated users or those with rights to do so, can access... you ask the server for the missing data (usually small pieces of json data) based on some CSRF token, or session_id, or both, (or any other server-side validation method you choose), and you render the template... otherwise you render a predefined error with the same template... Logic is simple enough...